# Dijkstra's shortest path with max intermediate nodes limitation

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

Suppose want to calculate the shortest path from one node to all other nodes, with the restriction of intermediate nodes cannot be more than a given number.

My major idea is, following how Dijkstra's algorithm works, with only the exception that when updating shortest path, if I see shortest path intermediate nodes exceeds the given number, I will skip the update. More details, refer to this line `and len(self.shortest_path[shortest_node_so_far]+[n[0]])-1 <= max_path_stop`

Here is my implementation, any advice on performance improvements in terms of algorithm time complexity, code bugs or code style are appreciated.

Test case is from wikipedia diagram (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

**Source code in Python 2.7**,

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connections = defaultdict(list)
        self.visited = set()
        self.shortest_path = defaultdict(list)
        self.shortest_path_distance = defaultdict(lambda : float('inf'))
    def add_edge(self, edge):
        self.connections[edge[0]].append((edge[1], edge[2]))
        self.connections[edge[1]].append((edge[0], edge[2]))
    def calculate_shortest_path(self, cur, max_path_stop):
        self.visited.add(cur)
        self.shortest_path[cur] = [cur]
        self.shortest_path_distance[cur] = 0
        for n,d in self.connections[cur]:
            self.shortest_path_distance[n] = d
            self.shortest_path[n].append(cur)
            self.shortest_path[n].append(n)
        while (len(self.visited) < len(self.connections.keys())):
            shortest_so_far = float('inf')
            shortest_node_so_far = None
            for n,d in self.shortest_path_distance.items():
                if n in self.visited:
                    continue
                if d <= shortest_so_far:
                    shortest_node_so_far = n
                    shortest_so_far = d
            self.visited.add(shortest_node_so_far)
            for n in self.connections[shortest_node_so_far]:
                if self.shortest_path_distance[shortest_node_so_far] + n[1] < self.shortest_path_distance[n[0]] \
                        and len(self.shortest_path[shortest_node_so_far]+[n[0]])-1 <= max_path_stop:
                    self.shortest_path_distance[n[0]]=self.shortest_path_distance[shortest_node_so_far] + n[1]
                    self.shortest_path[n[0]]=self.shortest_path[shortest_node_so_far]+[n[0]]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = Graph()
    edges = [(1,2,7),(1,3,9),(1,6,14),(2,3,10),(3,6,2),(5,6,9),(5,4,6),(3,4,11),(2,4,15)]
    for e in edges:
        g.add_edge(e)
    g.calculate_shortest_path(1,2)
    print g.shortest_path
    print g.shortest_path_distance
```

Answer (score 2):

If you apply your algorithm twice, as in

```
        g.calculate_shortest_path(1,3)
        ....
        g.calculate_shortest_path(1,2)
```

it would fail badly.

The reason is that `visited`, `shortest_path`, and `shortest_path_distance` are not, and cannot be, a property of `Graph` (especially `visited`). They are ephemeral properties of a particular traversal.

Questionably `shortest_path` and `shortest_path_distance` could be made properties of a vertex to allow for some optimization; I not quite sure it worths effort.

Comment: Thanks vpn, agree with you calling twice will fail, and vote up. What do you mean "made properties of a vertex"? Could you show code?

Comment: BTW, do you see any bugs in my code besides your above comments?

Comment: Hi vnp, if you could advise on my above questions, it will be great.